# Command button action not called JSF+Spring

Tags: spring, jsf

I have the following situation:

```
 <div class="row uniform">
                            <div class="12u">

                                <h:selectOneMenu id="mcm3" value="#{evaluateIdeaBean.committeeMemberEntity}"
                                                 styleClass="form-control"
                                                 requiredMessage="#{msg['global.msg.error.noInput']}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seçiniz" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{evaluateIdeaBean.allCMember}" var="committeeMember" itemLabel="#{committeeMember.user.fullName}" itemValue="#{committeeMember}"/>
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                                <!-- end of 2 -->
                        <div class="row uniform">
                            <div class="12u">
                                <ul class="actions" style="float:right;">

                                        <p:commandButton value="#{msg['btn.add']}"
                                                         icon="fa fa-plus"
                                                         ajax="false"
                                                         actionListener="#{evaluateIdeaBean.oneCommitteeMember}"
                                                         update="commiteMemberTable"
                                                         styleClass="noprint button small special_blue"
                                                         style="padding: 0 0.5em">
                                        </p:commandButton>
                                    </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

When I click the button, the method loginAction(), from my bean, it is not comming here code,

method ;

```
 public void oneCommitteeMember() {
    System.out.println("Ben buraya geldim");
    Evaluation tempEv;
    tempEv = evaluationService.findEvaluationByIdeaAndMember(ideaEntity,committeeMemberEntity);
    System.out.println(committeeMemberEntity.getUser().getFullName());
    if(tempEv==null) {
        tempEv=new Evaluation();
        tempEv.setCommitteeMember(committeeMemberEntity);
        tempEv.setIdea(ideaEntity);
        tempEv.setEvaluationDate();
        evaluationService.saveOrUpdate(tempEv);
        mailList.add(committeeMemberEntity.getUser().getEmail());
        Set<String> uniqueMailList = new HashSet<>();
        uniqueMailList.addAll(mailList);
        mailList.clear();
        mailList.addAll(uniqueMailList);

        // Send email to all committee members
        emailService.sendMail(mailList.toArray(new String[mailList.size()]),
                new String[0],
                properties.getMailSubject(this.getClass(), "02"),
                MessageFormat.format(properties.getMailBody(this.getClass(), "02"), ideaEntity.getTitle(), ideaEntity.getId()));
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

In this situation,when I press the commandbutton the method oneCommitteeMember() is not called, and I don't understand why.

I'm using jsf, primafaces,spring
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not set/updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value)

Comment: You need to do some debugging. Is the `FacesServlet` being hit?